# Mirror Maker 2 topic mirroring scenarios for Producers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have a question about the failover in the scenario.
Let's say that we have two clusters K1 and K2 and configured MM2 replication for TOPIC1 (originally created in just `K1`).

We configured the active-active replication:

```
K1->K2.enabled = true
K2->K1.enabled = true
K1->K2.topics = .*
K2->K1.topics = .*
```

On starting mirror maker 2, I see that topics are replicated from cluster `K1` to `K2` in the naming format `K1.topic_name_here` and vice versa for topics from cluster `K2` to `K1`.

I see that there was no topic `TOPIC1` created in `K2`, only `K1.TOPIC1` was created. I see this scenario working for consumers, as in the beginning the consumers consume `TOPIC1` from cluster `K1`. When the cluster `K1` out of service, fail over happens. Consumers start to consume `K1.TOPIC1` from `K2`.

My questions are as follows:

1. For producers, they won't producer to the topic `K1.TOPIC1` in cluster K2, my question is how do the producers go about producing data. Do I need to manually create a topic `TOPIC1` in cluster K2 and this topic will be used for producing messages to when failover happens.
2. If the above scenario is true, how do I move back to my primary cluster K1. As, now the topic `TOPIC1` in cluster K2 has digressed from the topic `TOPIC` in K1. How do we sync the messages in this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to address that is to introduce the concept of "local" and "remote" topics.

In a cluster, a "local" topic is a topic that you created in this cluster. A "remote" topic is a topic that was created by MirrorMaker2 and is typically prefixed (or suffixed) with a cluster alias, for example `K1.TOPIC1`.

Then to prevent "local" and "remote" topics from diverging, have your producers always produce to "local" topics and have consumers subscribed to both "local" and "remote" topics.

In your example:

- Producers always use `TOPIC1` whether they are connected to `K1` or `K2`.
- Consumers subscribe to `TOPIC1`, `K1.TOPIC1`, `K2.TOPIC1` (you can also use a pattern, such as `.*TOPIC1`)

If you want to preserve strict ordering, when switching clusters, you can make your consumers drain the remote topics first and then consume from the local topics.